# Parsing through text file in Python and printing the line matching the String

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a file named file.txt which contains some text. There is an another file details.txt containing the strings to be fetched from file.txt and print the line matching the strings from details.txt.

**files.txt**

```
12345 04/04/19 07:06:55  entered | computer message|  ID WRE435TW: headway | | 
23456 04/04/19 07:10:00  entered | computer message|  Double vehicle logon  | | 
23567 04/04/19 07:06:55  entered | computer message|  ID EWFRSDE3: small   | | 
09872 04/04/19 07:07:47  entered | computer message|  Double vehicle logon  | | 
76789 04/04/19 07:10:05  entered | computer message|  Veh : logoff          | |
```

**details.txt**

```
headway
small
logoff
logon
```

I Tried parsing the text file but not not getting the proper formatted output.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
import glob
import csv


os.chdir("file_path")

with open("file.txt", "r") as fp:
    with open("details.txt", 'r+') as f:
        for i in f:
            for line in fp:
                if i:
                    print(i)
                else:
                    print('no Event')
```

Comment: Have you tried to read files into pandas dataframe and then perform merge ?

Comment: @KlemenKoleša Tried converting to pandas dataframe but not getting proper indexing of strings that needs to be matched

Answer (score 1):

Just use Pandas POWER:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read the file as CSV with custom delimiter
df = pd.read_csv(
    'files.txt',
    delimiter='|',
    header=None
)
```

We will get it:

```
    0                                   1                   2                     3 4
0   64834 04/04/19 07:06:55 entered     computer message    Veh SBS3797R: headway       
1   73720 04/04/19 07:10:00 entered     computer message    Double vehicle logon        
2   64840 04/04/19 07:06:55 entered     computer message    Veh SBS3755L: small         
3   67527 04/04/19 07:07:47 entered     computer message    Double vehicle logon        
4   73895 04/04/19 07:10:05 entered     computer message    Veh : logoff
```

Pick the third column (with index 2) and transform it:

```
words = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.strip().split(' ')[-1])(df[2].values)
```

`np.vectorize` applies the function `lambda x: x.strip().split(' ')[-1]` (clean the text and pick the last word) to the third column `df[2].values`

So you can write it to the result file:

```
with open("details.txt", 'a+') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(words))
```

Note, that you should use `a+` to append to the result file. `r` prohibit to do it.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to print  those  lines from files.txt  that match the strings present in details.txt.

Comment: Well, you will have array of words in `words` variable. Just read all words from the `details.txt` and check them. You can easily do it by converting lists to sets: `waka = set(words)` and intersect them like: `result = waka & waka2`

Comment: Suppose there is a string 'headway' from a file detail.txt.

It will check for the  string('headway') in file.txt for every line and if the match is found it will print 
12345 04/04/19 07:06:55  entered | computer message|  ID WRE435TW: headway | |

Answer (score 1):

Notice that string different than `''` in python is consider as `True`. So in your code:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fp:
    with open("details.txt", 'r+') as f:
        for i in f:
            for line in fp:
                if i:  # This is always true (for input you showed)
                    print(i)
                else:
                    print('no Event')
```

You could try this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fp:
    with open("details.txt", 'r+') as f:
        for i in f:
            for line in fp:
                if i in line:  
                    print(line)  # I assume you wanted to print line from files.txt
                else:
                    print('no Event')
```